# Nvidia drivers issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 and upgraded the graphics card drivers to Nvidia 340 (instead of nouveau xorg). I could login normally, and even launch some app, but the screen turned to black after a couple of minutes (complete black, no mouse cursor or anything else). I tried to boot in safe mode but then I couldn't even get to the login screen.
So I had to completely reinstall the system, and the laptop is working fine with the nouveau-xorg drivers,  but I have these two questions:
Would the display be better with some nvidia drivers?
How to fix the issue I had?

My card is an nvidia 8800GTS.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is not to install proprietary drivers for these old cards.

My experience tells me that you will not get any better performance. And new Nvidia drivers (even 340) do not always support these cards well.

But if you plan to experiment, you need to learn uninstalling the drivers if the system does not boot to GUI. You do not have to re-install your system for that.

You can boot to recovery mode using grub menu, select `root` and run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get purge nvidia*
reboot
```

That will return to `nouveau` driver.

And do not try to install anything from `.run` files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and precise answer. I would leave the system as it is then.
Regards